# Python requests.get(url, timeout=75) does not wait for specified timeout

Tags: python, timeout, python-requests

```
requests.get("http://172.19.235.178", timeout=75)
```

is my piece of code.

It is trying a get request on the url which is a phone and is supposed to wait upto 75 seconds for it to return a 200OK.

This request works perfectly on one Ubuntu machine but does not wait for 75 seconds on another machine.

Comment: What does it do instead? Does it wait longer that 75 seconds?

Comment: it timesout ina bout 10-15 secs

Comment: Does it return the expected result?

Comment: no.. basically im checking if the phone is up or not. If it does not return response after 75 secs, I have my logic to handle and say that the phone is down. But one one host, the request does not wait till 75 secs. Is there any environment variable that i may need to set?

Answer (score 0):

according the documentation on https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts you can set a timeout in the requests connection part but the timeout you are encountering is an OS related socket timeout.

notice that if you do:

```
requests.get("http://172.19.235.178", timeout=1)
```

you get:

> **ConnectTimeout**: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.19.235.178', port=80):
>   Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to 172.19.235.178 timed out. (connect
>   timeout=1)'))

while when you do

```
requests.get("http://172.19.235.178", timeout=75)
```

you get:

> **ConnectionError**: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.19.235.178', port=80): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
>   10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

while you could change you OS behavior as stated here: http://willbryant.net/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout

In your case I would put a timeout of 10 and iterate over it a few times with a try except statement